# tizen listview example with separated IListViewItemProvider? (Native app)

Tags: listview, provider, tizen, tizen-native-app

i was looking for an example of use of listviews on tizen, the one that comes with the official samples its not quite clear....

i have no idea how to implement the IListViewItemProvider outside the scene, is it possible to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by _"implement outside the scene"_? Can you show us the code you've got that isn't working / that you find unclear?

Comment: I mean how do i create an independant IListViewItemProvider Class, as we do in android with adapters

Comment: Hope you can help me:
.h implementation of my itemprovider
http://pastebin.com/Uy3MDvQa

.cpp implementation:
http://pastebin.com/v01N803f

what i want is to do this on my form:

MyListItem* myItemProvider = new MyListItem();
__pListView->SetItemProvider(myItemProvider);

but i got this error

"no matching member function for call to 'SetItemProvider'"